# Read method in classes for Temperature Class in c++

Tags: c++, class, methods

I am trying to use a read method to read in a value for a temperature and a character for Fahrenheit or Celsius. I can't find anything on a read method in my programming book. I also have to change my for loop in my main program to loop over a range of values, but that isn't working either.  This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Interface for Temperature class
class Temperature
{
public:
   Temperature();
   Temperature(const Temperature & Temp);
   ~Temperature();
   double getCelsius() const;
   double getFahrenheit() const;
   void setCelsius(double Temp);
   void setFahrenheit(double Temp);
   void print();
   void read();

private:
   static const double ABSOLUTE_ZERO = -273.15;
   double CelsiusTemperature;
};

// Implementation of Temperature class
void Temperature::print()
{
      cout << getFahrenheit() << "F = " << getCelsius() << "C\n";
}
void Temperature::read()
{
   double num;
   char C;

   cin >> num >> C;
   cin >> num >> C;
   if (C != 'F' || C != 'f' || C != 'C' || C != 'c')
     cout << " ";
} 
Temperature::Temperature()
{
   CelsiusTemperature = 0;
}
Temperature::Temperature(const Temperature & Temp)
{
   CelsiusTemperature = Temp.CelsiusTemperature;
}

Temperature::~Temperature()
{
}   

double Temperature::getCelsius() const
{
   return CelsiusTemperature;
}

double Temperature::getFahrenheit() const
{
   return 9.0 * CelsiusTemperature / 5.0 + 32.0;
}

void Temperature::setCelsius(double Temp)
{
   CelsiusTemperature = Temp;
   if (CelsiusTemperature < ABSOLUTE_ZERO)
      CelsiusTemperature = ABSOLUTE_ZERO;
}

void Temperature::setFahrenheit(double Temp)
{
   CelsiusTemperature = (Temp - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0 ;
   if (CelsiusTemperature < ABSOLUTE_ZERO)
      CelsiusTemperature = ABSOLUTE_ZERO;
}

// Program to test Temperature class
int main()
{
   Temperature Start;
   Temperature End;
   Temperature Temp;
   cout << "Enter start temperature: ";
   Temp.read();
   cout << "Enter end temperature: ";
   Temp.read();

   cout.precision(3);
   for (F = Start; F <= End; F++)
   {
      Temperature Temp;
      Temp.setFahrenheit(F);
      Temp.print();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- You don't initialize `Start` or `End`
- Your `read` function doesn't set `CelsiusTemperature`
- You don't declare the variable `F`
- You use the same `Temp` variable to read both the start and end temperatures
- You don't have any specific comparison operators defined for the `Temperature` class, or any casting operator to cast it to integer/floating point values, neither have you a non-explicit constructor taking a value that is not a `Temperature`

Comment: How should I initialize Start and End?